# How to remove double quotes from the table and column names in the system when using pgSQL in abp vnext

Tags: abp, vnext

How to remove double quotes from the table and column names in the system when using pgSQL in abp vnext. For example, if the system defaults to select "TenantId" from "AbpUser", I would like the system to use the select tenant Id from abpuser when querying. Because my database table and column names are created in lowercase.

My system database was migrated from SQL SERVER, and after migration, it indicates that both the database and column names are lowercase without double quotes.